# SQL Server 2008 Unspecified error (MS Visual Database Tools)

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-diagram

I am a newbie using SQL Server 2008, and I am facing an error message when I try to make database diagram by right clicking on the database in SQL Server Management Studio:

> Unspecified error
>   (MS Visual Database Tools)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn
>   origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions,
>   IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn
>   origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions,
>   IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn
>   origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions,
>   IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateDesigner(DocumentType
>   editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, Urn parentUrn,
>   IManagedConnection mc, String fileName)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection
>   mc, DocumentOptions options)

I have searched for this error and most of the responses were about "common error when upgrading from 2005 to 2008", which is not my case, because I have only just newly installed SQL Server 2008 4 days ago.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you happen to have SQL 2005 or Visual Studio 2005 installed? Someone having the same error [here](http://databaselevellock.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/database-diagrams-sql-server-2005-on.html) solved this by uninstalling both, then re-installing SQL server 2008.

Comment: No I don't have 2005 in my computer, my computer was a completely new computer with only I.E. when I first took over it last week...

Answer (score 2):

I had this error today. It had nothing to do with migration from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 in my case. To solve the problem, I restarted my SQL Server 2008 and, in the authentication window, I changed the "Authentication" field from "Windows Authentication" to "SQL Server Authentication". I have no idea how I had ended up on "Windows Authentication" in the first place but changing it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Increase the no of connections is the solution.

By default, it is 4

right-click on SQL server instance and go to property

from there click on connections tab

[sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZNxX.png)

and increase user connections connected to higher number instance